# How to "swap" two values in an array?

Tags: java, selection

I am trying to write a selection sort algorithom. As part of the algorithom I need to switch 2 values in the array, I tryed it as follows: `array[min] = array[i]; array[i] = array[min];` But I belive this wont work because `array[min]` will already be `=` to `array[i]`. So how do I do this swap? bellow is my code.

```
static int[] array = {3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6};

static int n = 5;
static int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
        int min = 0;

        for (int j = i+1; j<=n; j++) {
            //System.out.println(j);

            if (array[j]<array[min]) {
                min = j;
            }

            if (min != i) {
                array[min] = array[i];
                array[i] = array[min];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need a temp mem location to store a value.

i.e.

```
temp = array[min]    
array[min] = array[i]    
array[i] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap values without using temp variable too. Sample code goes like this:

For an example:

```
array[min] = 10;
array[i] = 5;
```

Now,

```
array[min] = array[min] + array[i]; // array[min] = 15
array[i] = array[min] - array[i]; // array[i] = 10
array[min] = array[min] - array[i]; // array[min] = 5
```

Here you can avoid the use of temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to swap:

- **With a third temporary variable**

  ```
  temp = array[min];
  array[min] = array[i];
  array[i] = temp;
  ```
- **Without a temporary variable** (Using addition)

  ```
  array[min] = array[min] + array[i];
  array[i] = array[min] - array[i];
  array[min] = array[min] - array[i];
  ```
- **Without a temporary variable** (Using bit operations)

  ```
  array[min] ^= array[i];
  array[i] ^= array[min];
  array[min] = array[i];
  ```

  Here `^` is the Bitwise [XOR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_XOR_%5E).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some fun!
Any Big 0 Constraints? Memory constraints? If not I would  try this guy's simple bubble sort with the swap

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] Database) {

        for (int i = arraySize -1; i > 0; i--) {

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

                if(Database[j] > Database[j+1]){

                    Swap(Database,j,j+1);
                    //ArrayPartition.DisplayTheArray(i, j)

                }
                Main.PrintHorizontalArray(i, j);

            }

        //  Main.PrintHorizontalArray(i, -1);
        }

    }

    public static void Swap(int[] database, int j, int i) {
        int temp = database[j];
        database[j] = database[i];
        database[i] = temp;

}
```

I take zero credit for this answer as sorting was not covered in my college Java classes and I googled this to learn it.
[a great starting point to learn data structure and sorting.](https://github.com/hunter4sure/Java-Algorithms-Datastructures-)

There is also a great java 7 book for free that covers these

[javanotes](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s4.html)

I looked up my Java 7 class I used this code here

```
public int[] selectionSort(int[] inarray) {

//int[] data = Arrays.copyOf(inarray, inarray.length);
int temp;
int n=inarray.length;
for (int i=0; i<inarray.length; i++){
int k=i;
for (int j=i+1;j < n;j++)
if (inarray[j]<inarray[k])
k=j;
temp = inarray[i];
inarray[i] = inarray[k];
inarray[k] = temp;
}
return data;
}
```